# Como manter o contexto de uma Lista fora da Thread

Tags: java, thread, threadpool

Queria carregar a lista na Thread e depois ter acesso a mesma após o termino da ação.

Tem este código mas ao termino da thread a lista esta null;

alguém teria um dica para me ajudar?

```
public class ThreadListarClientes {
    private List<Cliente> clientes = null;
    ClienteCTR clienteCTR = new ClienteCTR();
    private Integer contaid = null;

    public ThreadListarClientes carregarThreadListarClientes() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {  

            @Override
            public void run() {      
                clientes = clienteCTR.listar(contaid, "clienteid", false);  
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        while (thread.getState() != Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
        return clientes;
    }

    public void setClientes(List<Cliente> clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
    }

    public Integer getContaid() {
        return contaid;
    }

    public void setContaid(Integer contaid) {
        this.contaid = contaid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual linguagem? Java?

Comment: sim... mas na verdade acho que o meu problema é que o Hibernate não aceita ser chamado dentro  da Thead

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar outras estruturas que te ajudarão a controlar a lista concorrente:

1. **CopyOnWriteArrayList** ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html))([exemplo](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/concurrency/java-concurrent-collection-copyonwritearraylist-examples)): essa solução faz uma
   cópia dos elementos que terão operações de escrita. Desse modo,
   operações de leitura acessam uma cópia diferente. Indicado quando
   você tem algumas atualizações ou inserções na estrutura e muitas
   leituras. Podemos dizer que a principal diferença para um ArrayList
   é que essa estrutura é thread-safe.
2. **Collections.synchronizedList**(list): essa outra forma de controlar
   bloqueia toda a lista pois usa a mesma cópia para as operações de
   leitura e escrita.